# jQuery Form Plugin sends duplicate emails

Tags: jquery, email, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using jQuery Form Plugin on a site for getting details from a user. When pressing "submit" sometimes I'm recieiving duplicate e-mails to my gmail account. I've tried to debug it by sending forms from different browsers, but my tries ended up in 1 mail, others give me 5 duplicated emails. Duplicate emails are "sent on the same time".

Regarding to double-clicking, my script hides the button after clicking on it, so that's not our problem.

I'm using ajaxForm method.

That's kinda annoying... any help? Is something wrong in my code or maybe a server-side problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is happening because of post back,can u provide your code?so that i can tell you exact problem.

Comment: How would you know that he is using ASP.net :)

Comment: `Try This:

$('#submit').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
// rest of your code
}); `

Answer (score 0):

It happens when user click the submit button twice and form get posted twice. There are different ways to stop [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019666/prevent-double-form-submission-in-jquery) and  [this](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol5/html_no16.htm) post may help you to do that

Comment: u would be hiding button using javascript. may be browser javascript is disabled. I ve seen this issue also. Only client side solution is not enough. try to follow the cookie solution or try to add server side check for duplicate post. Which server side technology you are using?